# Autodesk Large Model Viewer - View point cloud in recap file from ACC

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, point-clouds, autodesk, autodesk-construction-cloud

I am trying to view recap files in ACC that have point clouds. I found this post:

[How to get Autodesk Forge Viewer to support .rcp files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73329077/how-to-get-autodesk-forge-viewer-to-support-rcp-files)

But cannot get this to work, the recap viewer loads but comes up with an error stating the project can't be read due to view and download permissions. The only difference is that i am using a two legged token, does this matter? Has anyone else got this working?

Comment: Hi Connor, can you try the 3LO repo example mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73329077/how-to-get-autodesk-forge-viewer-to-support-rcp-files/76588951#76588951