# APS Custom Viewer for RCP file

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, point-clouds

we need to build a custom viewer to show a point cloud file (RCP extension) and interact with it.
We uploaded an RCP file on our ACC HUB and we notice that is possible to view it in the ACC viewer.
[RCP file on ACC HUB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kfc6.jpg)
Is it possible to view it also in a custom viewer? Can you provide us an example?

TIA
Alder

Comment: please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73329077/how-to-get-autodesk-forge-viewer-to-support-rcp-files